# Separating a class in another file if it's __init__ depends on another class' methods

Tags: python-3.x, class, python-import, instance-variables, separation-of-concerns

I want to split the python script into separate files but have python interpreter treat it as one - not Import (with all the namespace consequences) but more like "in this place insert code from another file"

The reason is pure convenience: the class I separate will be edited to enhance the functionality while I don't want to mess up the rest of the code. Preferably I would have PyCharm treat both files as one when editing, with code hints etc.

Is it possible?

**Main.py:**

```
import logic

class Clock:
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = 0
        self.timer = 0

    ## rest of the code

clock = Clock()
decoder = logic.Decoder()
```

**Logic.py:**

```
class Decoder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.do()

    @staticmethod
    def do():
       if clock.state == 1:
            print("T: " + ic.state.__str__())
```

Will end in:

> NameError: name 'clock' is not defined

Comment: Your explanation of what you're looking for isn't very clear.  Could you come up with an example that demonstrates it?

Comment: Maybe you're better off with C++